# ValueConverter with multiple arguments

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, imultivalueconverter

I'm trying to write a control that has three related properties: value, minimum and maximum. Value changes, but minimum and maximum are fixed.

So I wrote a IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class AngleMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double value = (double)values[0];
        double minimum = (double)values[1];
        double maximum = (double)values[2];

        double angle = -150.0 + ((value - minimum) * 300.0 / (maximum - minimum));
        return angle;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The XAML looks like the following (it's a custom control, hence the RelativeSource stuff):

```
<RotateTransform.Angle>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource angleMultiConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:KnobControl}}"/>
        <Binding Path="MinimumValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:KnobControl}}" Mode="OneWay"/>
        <Binding Path="MaximumValue" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:KnobControl}}" Mode="OneWay"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</RotateTransform.Angle>
```

That works fine, but what about ConvertBack? I have to pass back three values... but I only have one? The other two are constants, so how do I know what they are?

My other solution that works is to create a dependancy property called Angle which does all the work in a custom control... but exposes Angle which seems wrong.

Comment: You don't need to implement convertback unless you are using a twoway binding. Are min/max always the same for every call to that converter?

Comment: I am wondering why you would need a ConvertBack method? 
Let's say I have a number, e.g. 10.0. From only seeing the number it is impossible to guess the min and max values for the range this number is inside (but that would be what your ConvertBack method would have to do).

Comment: Just use the `ConverterParameter` to pass in your two missing values.

Comment: @bonyjoe It's a two way binding on the value (but not min/max) so yes I do need ConvertBack.

Comment: I tried ConverterParameter='20,20000' but that's hard coded - in the generic.xaml file. I really want to use the min/max value property of the control, but I can't see a way to do that in XAML.

Comment: Pity the converter doesn't have access to the control itself as a context. I did try working with the control itself, instead of a value, but ConvertBack was an issue again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I've found is create a property called Angle and let that do the work, as I originally pointed out in my question, and bonyjoe concluded.

Answer (score 0):

If your Min and Max values never change then you can just have them as properties on the Converter and use a normal IValueConverter to do the conversion, then you are only binding a single value.

You can pass values to the converter at creation time like so

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <utils:AngleConverter Min="20" Max="2000" x:Key="angleConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If you want to bind these properties it may be possible to use DependencyObject as the base class for the converter and create Min and Max as dependency properties instead of standard properties, though I have never tried this

Custom Control Implementation

In constructor

```
this.Resources.Add("AngleConverter", new AngleConverter() { Min = _min, Max = _max });
```

In Min/Max value changed

```
((AngleConverter)this.Resources["AngleConverter"]).Min = newMin;
((AngleConverter)this.Resources["AngleConverter"]).Max = newMax;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for a custom control though, as the converter is used by the control template. Everything would have the same min/max; I'd want the converter to refer to the min/max of the current control.

Comment: You can create the resource programmatically after the Min and Max have been set?

Comment: I've added code to do it programmatically to my answer

Comment: Aren't you changing a global resource rather than one specific to each control?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources(v=vs.110).aspx

Note that this property returns only the resource dictionary declared directly within that element. This is different than the actual resource lookup process, where a child element can access any of the resources defined in each parent element, searching recursively upwards.

Comment: Ah... I tried setting the resources as you say. It doesn't work as I think I'm changing an instance of the converter that's not being used. I think I'd need to get into the 'Angle={Binding Value, Converter=...' and set the converter, otherwise it'll use the one in XAML.

Comment: Have you removed your old angleConverter resource?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work as I explained. I'd need to set the Converter on the Angle binding of the RotationTransform.

Comment: After doing some testing it looks like this isn't really possible with a converter. I think it would just make more sense to have an extra Angle property and handle the logic when Angle or Value changes.